# How to update a custom variable in BaseAdapter?

Tags: android, baseadapter, notifydatasetchanged

In Android, I have write a class

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private Cursor imageCursor;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, Cursor imageCursor) {
        this.context = context;
        this.imageCursor = imageCursor;
    }
}
```

In this code, I want to update value of *imageCursor* variable when I call notifyDataSetChanged() method.
How I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either override notifyDatasetChanged() and put your code before you call super.notifyDatasetChanged, or create a custom method like this,

```
public void updateNotifyDatasetChanged(Cursor newImageCursor){
    this.imageCursor = newImageCursor;
    notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Haha no worries, sometimes it just takes another set of eyes on a problem.